# Symfony 2 + Doctrine 2: find a record based on a date field using a DateTime value

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity called `Event`, with a field `startDate` (type="date"), and another called `slug` (type="string"). I have created a controller action to get a specific event based on these parts. The router passes eventDate as the format 'Y-m-d', and the eventSlug. Now I have successfully created a DateTime object with `$startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $eventDate)`. Now if I issue

```
$event = $eventRepo->findOneBy(array(
    'startDate' => $startDate,
    'slug'      => $eventSlug,
));
```

it gets nothing (`$event` is NULL). Do I miss something in Doctrine documentation, or did I find a bug?

Comment: If I leave the startDate part and use only the slug, it works like charm, so the problem is in the startDate thing for sure.

Answer (score 2):

First ensure that actually an `Event` with the given slug and start date exists. Is `slug` unique field?

Anyway you can let Doctrine do the param conversion for you, without using PHP `format` function:

```
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeHelloBundle:Event');
$qb   = $repo->createQueryBuilder('e');

$event = $qb
    ->andwhere($qb->expr()->eq('e.slug', ':slug'))
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('e.start_date', ':start_date'))
    ->setParameter('slug', $eventSlug)
    ->setParameter('start_date', $startDate)
    ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Or, use the Doctrine param converter:

```
/**
 * @Route("/event/show/{slug}/{start_date}")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @ParamConverter("event", class="AcmeHelloBundle:Event")
 * @Template
 */
public function showAction(Event Event)
{
}
```

Internally, Doctrine param converter do it for you: It checks for any parameter in the request and find an entity using `slug` and `start_date`.