# Send the selected option name to annotations (Route)

Tags: php, symfony

Hey I am trying to get the selected option value in my route (annotation). I have Portfolio Controller which contains Index view. Inside the index view there is a form with only one select drop down. Initially the URL looks like

```
http://localhost/idp/web/app_dev.php/portfolio/
```

The form inside the index view is

```
<form name="portfolios" action="{{ path('v2_pm_portfolio_switch') }}" method="post" >
    <select name="portfolio" style="width: 200px; height:25px;">
        <option selected="selected" value="default">Switch Your Portfolio</option>
        {% for portfolio in portfolios %}
            <option value={{ portfolio.id }}>{{ portfolio.portfolioName }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
   <input type="submit"class="portfolio_input button2 tooltip" value="Switch">
</form>
```

When the user submit the form, it calls the `switchportfolio` Action (inside portfolio controller)
My switch portfolio Action is

```
/**
* Switch Portfolio action.
* @Route("/{user selected option name should come here}", name="v2_pm_portfolio_switch")
* @Secure(roles="ROLE_Normal_Registered_User")
* @Template("MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:Portfolio:index.html.twig")
*/
public function switchportfolioAction(Request $request){
    }
```

**How can I send the selected option name to my URL in Symfony2 ?**
So that, if the user select portofolio1, and submit the form the URL becomes :

```
http://localhost/idp/web/app_dev.php/portfolio/portfolio1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
/**
 * Switch Portfolio action.
 * @Route("/v2_pm_portfolio_switch", name="v2_pm_portfolio_switch")
 * ...
 */
public function switchPortfolioAction(Request $request){
    //check that the form parameters are OK and get the portfolio id from the request
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('show_portfolio',array('portfolio'=>$portfolioId)));                

}

/**
 * Show Portfolio action.
 * @Route("/portfolio/{portfolio)", name="show_portfolio")
 * ...
 */
public function showPortfolioAction($portfolio){
    //do whatever you need to show this portfolio
}
```

Comment: I will give it a try and will let you know... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTML forms do not behave like that. You'll need to add some javascript, that runs when the form is submitted, that stops the submission and changes the current location according to the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the right way to do so.

What I mean is that if you only want to have a form with a select that modifies the URL, you should not use POST as the form submit method. That would be more fitting for a GET method then.

This is to my opinion, not a Symfony2 question then.

You could either do like @carlos-granados is refering to, but instead of creating a forward, grab the submit event, and use javascript to redirect using `window.location` way [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669050/change-window-location-jquery)

### Adjust form

You could just drop the `<form>` `action=""` attribute and only fill each

```
<option value="{{ path('show_portfolio', { 'slug': portfolio.name }}">{{ portoflio.name }}</option>
```

Nodes which will generate the proper fully generated path. Then, make sure your `show_portfolio` has the `{slug}` ready to get the entry from the database with the proper

### Adjust Controller method

```
$entry = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Portoflio')->findBy(array('slug'=>$request->get('slug')));
```

But this is where I was going with my original answer. You should look for [`@ParamConverter`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) and [see for something similar to here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619514/symfony-2-doctrine-2-find-a-record-based-on-a-date-field-using-a-datetime-val)

### Then add javascript

```
$('form').submit(function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    window.location.href = $('form select').value(); 
});
```

Comment: I think you did not understand what he was trying to do